# What is the difference between utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs and utf8mb4_900_as_cs?

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm facing issues when building unit tests for my SQLALCHEMY api. I noticed that my MySQL DB returns an unexpected order when asking to order by a string column.
A little investigation showed that our DB is using utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs.
But when trying to order with utf8mb4_0900_as_cs, I get the expected order.

Can someone explain to me what are the differences between these 2 collations?

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     column_0 AS name1
    -> FROM
    ->     (VALUES
    ->         ROW('default_chanakah'),
    -> ROW('default_aaa'),
    -> ROW('default_zzz'),
    ->         ROW('default_hsunan'),
    ->         ROW('default_kourin1')
    ->     ) AS hardcodedNames
    -> ORDER BY
    -> name1
    -> COLLATE utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs;
+------------------+
| name1            |
+------------------+
| default_aaa      |
| default_hsunan   |
| default_chanakah |
| default_kourin1  |
| default_zzz      |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     column_0 AS name1
    -> FROM
    ->     (VALUES
    ->         ROW('default_chanakah'),
    -> ROW('default_aaa'),
    -> ROW('default_zzz'),
    ->         ROW('default_hsunan'),
    ->         ROW('default_kourin1')
    ->     ) AS hardcodedNames
    -> ORDER BY
    -> name1
    -> COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
+------------------+
| name1            |
+------------------+
| default_aaa      |
| default_chanakah |
| default_hsunan   |
| default_kourin1  |
| default_zzz      |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs` is Czech utf8 (first cs indicate this), this alphabet contains "letter" `Ch` and it goes after `h`

this is why **h**susan is before **ch**anakah

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography

[image]

Comment: Just for reference. In the utf8mb4_**LOCALE** _ 0900 _ ??_??  collation name, Czech lang is `cs` or `czech`, as per  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html , Table 10.3 Unicode Collation Language Specifiers

Comment: Meanwhile, `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs` is a generic collation -- pretty good for many languages but really good for few.